# Jupyter Notebook Unreadable because of error: Notebook does not appear to be JSON [Python]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was working in a Jupyter Notebook, I saved my work, rechecked it and everything looked fine. Three days later I try to open the same notebook and all I see is this error:

```
Unreadable Notebook: C:\Users\my_name\my_repos\my_folder\project_notebook.ipynb NotJSONError('Notebook does not appear to be JSON: \'{\\n "cells": [\\n {\\n "cell_type": "m...')
```

I do not know what this means or how to address this. I have never used JSON before ever. I don't know if this is an error with my python code or something else, because my code ran fine just a few days ago. How can I restore my notebook?

Comment: Have you read for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103772/unreadable-notebook-notjsonerrornotebook-does-not-appear-to-be-json-u-n ?

Comment: I see here that the issue could be with the JSON of the notebook, but I am not sure why this would have been changed if I never changed any JSON, nor even know how to. Another comment suggested that I could retrieve the notebook by looking in the '.ipynb_checkpoints' folder for hidden files.

Comment: "I am not sure why this would have been changed if I never changed any JSON, nor even know how to." It simply could arise as an incomplete or interrupted saving process. Going back to the checkpoints is a great suggestion and in the future using version control or Time Machine-like backup is highly advised. Sometimes it is just that your Windows machine or Jupyter gets finnicky and you can compare to an old version of it as text in a coding editor and fix it by hand.

Comment: What I was stumbling trying to say in my last comment is that you need to definitely examine the `.ipynb` file directly in a text editor. If the content is all there but there is something slightly out of whack about the JSON format then you should only be minorly inconvenienced. You can either move the good content to a new `.ipynb` by hand or use a Python script to move the content to a new `.ipynb` file you make with [nbformat](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#). But with the little details about the state of the file involved that you've shared it is hard to advise.